# How to set selected dates in multiDatesPicker

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-multidatespicker

I want to set selected dates in multiDatesPicker using php script which are comma separated values coming from the database. For example, this column 'Dates' having these values '02-05-2018, 15-05-2018, 27-05-2018'. How do I set/show these dates selected in multidatepicker.

```
<div id="myCalendar"></div>

$("#myCalendar").multiDatesPicker({

});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's pretty easy, the MultiDatesPicker plugin exposes a method for setting values via the `addDates` method:

```
$('#myCalendar').multiDatesPicker({
    addDates: ['5/2/2018','5/15/2018','5/27/2018','6/30/2018']
});
```

The `addDates` method ([documentation](http://dubrox.github.io/Multiple-Dates-Picker-for-jQuery-UI/#method-addDates)) states that "the parameter dates can be a string, a date object or an array (of strings or javascript date objects)."

Working jsFiddle here - you'll see June 30th selected as well as May 2nd, 15th & 27th.
http://jsfiddle.net/bbrgx3pg/2/